# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Philosophy's [second moderator election](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators is:

[image: Philip Klöcking]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with him as he learns the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4756667291926528/0).

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations on winning, Mr. Klöcking, and thank you for running, Rodrigo!

Answer (score 3):

Herzlichen Glückwunsch, Herr Klöcking! Danke für Ihren Service.

Answer (score 2):

Bravo Mr. Klöcking, and commiserations to the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Congratulation Philip. I'm looking forward to you as our new moderator.